# Why are 5-ringed saturated chelates more stable than unsaturated ones while 6-ringed unsaturated chelates are more stable than saturated ones?

Tags: coordination-compounds

5-ringed saturated chelates seem to be more stable than unsaturated ones. On the other hand, 6-ringed unsaturated chelates are more stable than saturated ones. Why do these hold true?